# OAuth Provider Service and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-ruby

I am trying to look into setting up an OAuth Provider Server with Rails 3 but can't seem to find anything out there to accomplish this.

I am also a newb when it comes to oauth, so excuse my ignorance.

When setting up an oauth server do I need to already have an oauth account at somewhere like agree2.com? Or can I just use my own server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set up an OAuth server, you don't need to have an account somewhere else, that is the whole point of a server. It's a little bit outdated, but perhaps it's a good starting point:
http://stakeventures.com/articles/2007/11/26/how-to-turn-your-rails-site-into-an-oauth-provider

Comment: there are to ways to reward a good answer, first you can upvote the answer with the up arrow above the number besides the answer. If an answer helped you to solve your problem you should accept it with the tick under the number.